# JS foreach - mouseenter event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Hello I'm trying to make responsive layout which changes when data is loaded.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: points">
    <div class="col-md-4" data-name="text: name" id="oferty">
        <h2><span data-bind="text: name"> </span></h2>
        <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code above gives me same result as a hard coded rows as below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" data-name="Test1" id="oferty">
        <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
        <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But my event script works only on that hardcoded:

```
$("#oferty.col-md-4").mouseenter(function () {
    console.log("wszedlem");        
}).mouseleave(function () {
    console.log("wyszedłem");
});
```

I think that problem is with Knockout bindings and its UI refresh. My layout renders correctly using my data but page source is unchanged and looks like this:

```
<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: points">
    <div class="col-md-4" data-name="text: name" id="oferty">
        <h2><span data-bind="text: name"> </span></h2>
        <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

so my Jquery script cant find #oferty.col-md-4 selector in foreach statement. Can anyone suggest me any workaround of this problem?

OK with your help I force to work but with little problems:

With event binding plus this code:

```
function mouseEnter()
{
    var poszukiwane = $(this).attr("data-name");
    console.log(poszukiwane);
}
function mouseOut()
{
    var poszukiwane = $(this).attr("data-name");
    console.log(poszukiwane);
}
```

I have to many function calls:
When enter: mouseEnter and mouseOut is called.
When leave mouseOut is called 2 times

with delegates:

```
$("div").delegate("#oferty.col-md-4", "mouseenter", function () {   
    console.log("delegate in"); 
});
$("div").delegate("#oferty.col-md-4", "mouseleave", function () {
    console.log("delegate out");
});
```

I have 4 calls when enter end 4 calls when leave.

Below my FullViewModel:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "empty" });
var markers = [];
var rows = [];

function point(name, lat, long) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.lat = lat;
    self.long = long;

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
    title: name,
    map: map,
    draggable: true
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
    console.log(marker.title);
    infowindow.setContent(marker.title);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);

}.bind(this)); 
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    alert(marker.title);
    console.log(marker.title);

}.bind(this));
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
    infowindow.close();
}.bind(this));
markers.push(marker);
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55, 11),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var viewModel = {
    points: ko.observableArray([
        new point('Test1', 55, 11),
        new point('Test2', 56, 12),
        new point('Test3', 57, 13)])    
};

$("#oferty.col-md-4")
    .mouseenter(function () {
        console.log("wszedlem");
        var poszukiwane=$(this).attr("data-name");
        //showMarkerFromMenu($(this).attr("data-name"));
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if (markers[i].title == poszukiwane) {
                infowindow.setContent(markers[i].title);
                infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);
            }
        }


    })
.mouseleave(function () {
    infowindow.close();
});
function mouseEnter()
{
    var poszukiwane = $(this).attr("data-name");
    console.log(poszukiwane);
}
function mouseOut()
{
    var poszukiwane = $(this).attr("data-name");
    console.log(poszukiwane);
}
/*
$("div").delegate("#oferty.col-md-4", "mouseenter", function () {   
    console.log("delegate in"); 
});
$("div").delegate("#oferty.col-md-4", "mouseleave", function () {
    console.log("delegate out");
});   */
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And nearly all layout:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section id="Map" class="fixed-location">
            <div id="googleMap" style="width:350px;height:600px;"></div>
        </section>
  </div> 
  <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: points">
            <div class="col-md-4" id="oferty"
                 data-bind="event: { mouseenter: mouseEnter, mouseout: mouseOut}, name: name">
                <h2><span data-bind="text: name"> </span></h2>
                <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" data-lat="50.12" data-lng="19.10" data-name="Test1" id="oferty">
                <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
                <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-lat="50.13" data-lng="19.10" data-name="Test2" id="oferty">
                <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
                <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" data-lat="50.14" data-lng="19.10" data-name="Test3" id="oferty">
                <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
                <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301866">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Scripts etc included and working but I didn't paste that fragment of code

Comment: Use delegated event handlers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are try to add mouseenter / mouseleave handlers before initialization viewModel.

You can try this solution:

```
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$("#oferty.col-md-4").mouseenter(function () {
    console.log("wszedlem");        
}).mouseleave(function () {
    console.log("wyszedłem");
});
```

But the best way is to use knockout event binding:

```
<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: points">
    <div class="col-md-4" data-name="text: name" id="oferty" 
       data-bind="event: { mouseenter: mouseEnter, mouseout: mouseOut}">
        <!-- Your layout -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

About:

```
data-name="Test1"
```

it should be like this:

```
data-bind="text: Name"
```

**Update2:**

You didn't deleted jQuery event handlers in your ViewModel. Delete them (starts from line $("#oferty.col-md-4")). Stay only mouseEnter, mouseLeave functions!

**Update3:**

Ok, i've debugged your code and found a lot of bugs. The reason of multiple mouseenter/mouseout calls is html element, where you've added event binding. MouseEnter/MouseLeave events calls for each child html element, so as you defined it for div, it called when you enter/leave child elements.

I've created a simple demo, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yxEEc/)

Comment: Thx. Your code fixed nearly half of my problems. I updated my question.

Comment: Please, in the next time, firstly accept your original question and then create a new. Don't add a new problems in your original question!

Comment: About your additional questions, did you add both bindings and jquery event handlers?

Comment: No. I first checked delegates.  Then comment them. And then Event bindigns.

Comment: After deleting same efect when enter mouseEnter and mouseOut called when leave mouseOut x2

Answer (score -2):

Please try this;

```
$("#oferty.col-md-4").on("mouseenter",function(){
  console.log("wszedlem");        
}).on("mouseleave",function(){
console.log("wyszedłem");
})
```